# how to solve classes parameter "self"

Tags: python, function, class, blockchain

I tried to execute the code to create class as client but the problem display  talk about the Self._public_key is not defined
...NameError: name 'self' is not defined

```
    # import libraries
    import hashlib
    import random
    import string
    import json
    import binascii
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import pylab as pl
    import logging
    import datetime
    import collections
    # following imports are required by PKI
    import Crypto
    import Crypto.Random
    from Crypto.Hash import SHA
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
    from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
    
    class Client:
        def __init__(self):
          random = Crypto.Random.new().read
          self._private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random)
          self._public_key = self._private_key.publickey()
          self._signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(self._private_key)
      
       
        def identity(self):
          return
    binascii.hexlify(self._public_key.exportKey(format='DER')).decode('ascii')
    
    Dinesh = Client()
    print (Dinesh.identity)
```

Comment: see `1` at end of last line bro

Comment: bro when i execute without it this just mistak in writting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing `binascii.hexlify(self._public_key.exportKey(format='DER')).decode('ascii')` at the next line. Try writing it after the `return` keyword. Hope your error will go away

Comment: thank you bro but again i want to see the public key codeing it is show just                    <bound method Client.identity of <__main__.Client object at 0x00000288BA0CFC40>>

Comment: then `return binascii.hexlify(Client._public_key.exportKey(format='DER')).decode('ascii')`

Answer (score 0):

you should define a Clinet instance and then get it's _public_key:

```
binascii.hexlify(Client._public_key.exportKey(format='DER')).decode('ascii')
```

Comment: but how i can to get public key as format f30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d0030818902818100b547fafceeb131e07
0166a6b23fec473cce22c3f55c35ce535b31d4c74754fecd820aa94c1166643a49ea5f49f72
3181ff943eb3fdc5b2cb2db12d21c06c880ccf493e14dd3e93f3a9e175325790004954c34d3
c7bc2ccc9f0eb5332014937f9e49bca9b7856d351a553d9812367dc8f2ac734992a4e6a6ff6
6f347bd411d07f0203010001

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `identity` property with the help of a function, not as a plain attribute. Modify your `identity()` function as follows:

```
def identity(self):
    idn = binascii.hexlify(self._public_key.exportKey(format='DER')).decode('ascii') # <------
    return idn # <------
```

And then, you can call it like:

```
Dinesh = Client()
print(Dinesh.identity())  # <------
```